# Repodata/repomd.xml not found

Tags: opensuse

I am using Opensuse and whenever i am going to install any software on it, It Shows me the error "linux-7gyx:~ # zypper in python-oauthlib Retrieving repository 'New' metadata --------------------------------------------------[] File '/repodata/repomd.xml' not found on medium 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/SUSE:/SLE-11:/SP3:/Update/standard/'"  What should i do to get rid of this type of error ,Please Help Me . Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the full stack trace of your error, hence apologies - I cannot provide a custom resolution.

I struggled with this issue for some time as well. Managed to resolve it just now. In my case, the error was -

```
repodata/repomd.xml from stackdriver: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

This happened when I tried to install stackdriver using a chef cookbook.

I started troubleshooting with the routine options of a 'yum clean all' and 'yum clean metadata'. Didn't help.

In due course I checked the yum repo file under '/etc/yum.repos.d'. The one related to the pack which I was trying to install (stackdriver) was the cause of the issue. Renamed that file and the issue was resolved - at least temporarily.

Of course, now I am trying to fix that repo file - but that is a secondary problem.

Hope this helps!